# What is the difference between a "sudo reboot" command and a "ipmitool power reset" command?

Tags: linux, sudo, reboot

From what I can find online `sudo reboot` and  `ipmitool power reset` are warm reboot commands

Are there actually any differences between these two or are they just the same thing with a different method to execute?

I could guess they are different due to the syntax but under the hood is it the same signals to the motherboard, just from a different input OR'ed together?

Answer (score 1):

sudo reboot normally runs the `shutdown -r` command, which closes running processes. ipmitool power reset triggers the same hardware reset mechanism but without calling shutdown.

Note that shutdown and reboot are links to the same file.  In the olden days, a script that did the orderly shutdown.  Now they are both links to systemctl.

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, if a process was interrupted with sudo reboot it will return an error code most likely but if a process was interrupted with ipmitool power reset the process will hang? This would explain the behavior I am seeing

Comment: shutdown sends a SIGTERM to all processes, giving them a chance to save data and exit gracefully.  If the power reset happens, then the process is immediately killed with no chance to save.

Comment: Okay I think I get it now, thanks for your speedy replies!

Comment: Are you aware of any other signals that do get asserted when ipmitool power reset is executed, such as SIGINT, SIGKILL or SIGQUIT?